# C program only takes input for the first prompt

Tags: c

My program only takes input for the first prompt and it excludes the succeeding ones, and instead, it just directly prints them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    // Initialize
    char cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB;
    float fCurrencyA;
    float fRate;
    
    // Prompt user for currency names
    printf("Enter a currency name: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);
    
    // Prompt user for the current rate
    printf("Enter the rate:");
    scanf("%f", &fRate);
    
    // Prompt user to enter value for currency A
    printf("Enter value for %c", cCurrencyA);
    scanf("%f", &fCurrencyA);
    
    // Convert currency A to B
    int nResult = fCurrencyA * fRate;
    
    // Print the result
    printf("%f%c is %d%c", fCurrencyA, cCurrencyA, nResult, cCurrencyB);
    return 0;
    
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a currency name:USD PHP
Enter the rate:
Enter value for U:
0.000000U is 0S
```

Comment: Dont'use scanf() directly on stdin. Use fgets() and sscanf() instead. Check return values.

Comment: Hint: print the numeric values of what was entered for `cCurrencyA` and `cCurrencyB`.

Comment: Why are you convering the currency to `int` value, not `float`?

Comment: I would just like to display a whole number instead of a decimal value

Comment: So when converting 10 rupee to dollars you want to see `0` output?

Comment: No, I would just like to somewhat round it off. For instance, if result is 10.2, it would just display 10

Comment: As I said, you convert 10 rupee to 0 dollars, when it is about 0.13 dollars, not 0. But what was the result of the suggested `printf("%d %d\n", cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB);`? And show exactly what you entered, in the question.

Comment: @Franz Zapanta, please post input used , output seen and output expected

Comment: already updated the post

Comment: @FranzZapanta Do you expect input "USD"` to fit in 1 `char`?

Comment: Still fixing that, as of now I'm concerned on why I'm only able to enter input on the first prompt

Comment: @FranzZapanta Had you entered only `"xy"` as you input instead of `"USD PHP"` - it would have "worked".

Comment: I just did, and it actually worked. I guess my problem is now in handling a string rather than just characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247942/discussion-between-franz-zapanta-and-chux-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. so you have major problems , you are scanning a whole string into only one `char` , that's wrong , you should do `char cCurrencyA[20], cCurrencyB[20];` not `char cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB;` to scan a string not only one `char`.
2. when you are scanning using `scanf()`, use the quantifier `%s` not `%c` , as  `%c` will get only one character but  `%s` will scan a whole string.
3. also to round the result , you could use `math` header file , by using the function called `lround()` , so do this `int nResult = round((double)fCurrencyA * fRate);`
   not `int nResult = fCurrencyA * fRate;` as the lValue is `int` while RValue is `float` so you have to cast it.

and here the code edited :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){

    // Initialize
    char cCurrencyA[20], cCurrencyB[20];
    float fCurrencyA;
    float fRate;

    // Prompt user for currency names
    printf("Enter a currency name: ");
    scanf("%19s %19s", cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB);

    // Prompt user for the current rate
    printf("Enter the rate:");
    scanf("%f", &fRate);

    // Prompt user to enter value for currency A
    printf("Enter value for %s", cCurrencyA);
    scanf("%f", &fCurrencyA);

    // Convert currency A to B
    int nResult = lround((double)fCurrencyA * fRate);

    // Print the result
    printf("%f%s is %d%s", fCurrencyA, cCurrencyA, nResult, cCurrencyB);
    return 0;

}
```

and here is the output :

```
Enter a currency name:USD PHP
Enter the rate:10.5
Enter value for USD10
10.000000USD is 105PHP
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `scanf("%s%s"` lacks a _width_ and is prone to buffer overrun.  Avoid ever using `"%s"` without a width like `"%19s"` for `char [20]`.

Comment: Aside:  Rather than `(int)round(...)`, consider `lround(...)` to round a `double` into a `long` in one step.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , I agree with you , I edit the code based on your suggestions.

Comment: This is giving me an error: convert.c:40:23: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%19s%19s", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);
           ~~~~       ^~~~~~~~~~~
convert.c:40:36: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%19s%19s", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);
               ~~~~                ^~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.

Comment: @FranzZapanta , I edited the code , the problem was that I supposed to write `scanf("%19s %19s", cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB);` not `scanf("%19s%19s", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);` , it's just about the operator **&** as the name of the array itself is the base address of the array and it's a warning not an error

Comment: @FranzZapanta Good that you had many warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1):

First line of input was 8 characters: `"USD PHP\n"`.

`scanf("%c%c", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);` only reads and saves the first 2 in `cCurrencyA`, `cCurrencyB`.

The remaining 6 are not numeric text for the next  `scanf("%f",...` so it does not assign anything and returns 0.  Same for the next `scanf("%f",...`.

---

Best to read a line of  user input with `fgets()`  and then parse the string.

---

Yet if one *must* use the problematic `scanf()`, read currency names as a string.

```
// char cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB;
char cCurrencyA[100], cCurrencyB[100];

// scanf("%c%c", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);
scanf("%99s %99s", cCurrencyA, cCurrencyB);

// printf("%f%c is %d%c", fCurrencyA, cCurrencyA, nResult, cCurrencyB);
printf("%f%s is %d%s\n", fCurrencyA, cCurrencyA, nResult, cCurrencyB);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `scanf` with the `%c` conversion format specifier, `scanf` will only match a single character. Therefore, with the input `USD PHP`, the function call

```
scanf("%c%c", &cCurrencyA, &cCurrencyB);
```

will match the `U` and the `S`, but `D PHP` will be left on the input stream. Afterwards, the function calls

```
scanf("%f", &fRate);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", &fCurrencyA);
```

will both fail, because `scanf` is unable to convert `D PHP` to a floating-point number.

If you want to use `scanf` to match a whole word, you could use the `%s` format specifier instead, but you should normally limit it to the size of the memory buffer. For example, if the size of the memory buffer is `4`, then you could use `%3s` as the format specifier, which limits the number of matched characters to `3`, so that you still have room for the terminating null character.

However, it is generally not recommended to use `scanf` for line-based user input, because, as you have now discovered yourself, `scanf` does not always behave in an intuitive manner, because it does not always read one line at once.

For this reason, you may want to consider using the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function instead, which always reads exactly one line of input at once, if possible.

Therefore, I recommend that you first read an entire line of input as a string using `fgets`, and then use [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and/or maybe [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to parse the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[100];
    char strCurrencyA[4], strCurrencyB[4];
    float fCurrencyA, fRate, fResult;
    
    // Prompt user for currency names
    printf( "Enter a currency name: " );
    fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );
    sscanf( line, "%3s %3s", strCurrencyA, strCurrencyB );
    
    // Prompt user for the current rate
    printf( "Enter the rate: " );
    fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );
    fRate = strtof( line, NULL );
    
    // Prompt user to enter value for currency A
    printf("Enter value for %s: ", strCurrencyA);
    fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );
    fCurrencyA = strtof( line, NULL );
    
    // Convert currency A to B
    fResult = fCurrencyA * fRate;
    
    // Print the result
    printf( "%0.2f %s is %0.2f %s", fCurrencyA, strCurrencyA, fResult, strCurrencyB);

    return 0;    
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter a currency name: USD PHP
Enter the rate: 56.8
Enter value for USD: 25
25.00 USD is 1420.00 PHP
```

Note that this program does not perform any input validation. It will probably misbehave if the input is invalid in any way.